# Split/separate in array string by some rules

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I need to separate string like

```
1FS-2y 4f 5f
```

And get array like

```
1,FS,-,2,y, ,4,f, ,5,f
```

Whether there is a easy way to do it?

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what are the rules ?

Comment: My english not good and i can't to explain my problem another way. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string.match` instead of `string.split`

```js
var s = "1FS-2y 4f 5f";
alert(s.match(/[A-Za-z]+|\W+|\d+/g))
```

Comment: Is it Regular Expression? if not what is this pattern and how to write sth like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to get the result

```
function splitString(data){
    if(data){
        return data.match(/[A-Za-z]+|\W+|\d+/g);
    }
}
```

this will give you the desired result.

```
Call
splitString("1FS-2y 4f 5f");

Output 

["1", "FS", "-", "2", "y", " ", "4", "f", " ", "5", "f"]
```